# ThenInclude with many to many in EF Core

Tags: database, web, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables:

```
public class Parent
  {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
  }
```

```
public class Person
  {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
  }
```

```
public class Friend
  {
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    public long FriendId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FriendId")]
    public Person Friend { get; set; }
  }
```

The Friend table is a many-to-many relationship between two rows of the Person table. It has a PK composed from the PersonId and the FriendId, declared like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>(entity =>
      {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.PersonId, e.FriendId });
      });

modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Friend)
        .WithMany()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I want to get all parents with all persons and all their friends, which would look like this:

```
var entities = context.Parents
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(c => c.Persons)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.Friends)
        .ToList();
```

However this does not get the data from the Friends table.

If I inlcude the friends in a person query without the parent it works:

```
var entities = context.Persons
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.Friends)
        .ToList();
```

I am using EF Core version 2.2 .

How can I make the first query to retrieve the firends of a person as well and what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Then naming of entities and properties is confusing. It's not clear what you intend to be primary key or foreign key. I recommend you adhere to common naming conventions (which also includes removing this 'Entity' suffix). Also, please specify the exact EF version you're using.

Comment: Updated the post as mentioned by @GertArnold.

Comment: Now your cde doesn't compile (property `Friend` in class `Friend`). And this is two 1:n relationships (not m:n) where one entity (`Friend`) has an unusual composite key which results in multiple cascade paths. Please turn this into working code or show the original model from which your question originates.

Comment: My intention was to add an m:n relation where a person can have many friends and a person can be many other persons friend. Is this not the right way to achieve that? I forgot to add the multiple cascade paths code, which I added now.